# Can you change the "Customer" label in salesforce communities?

Tags: community

I am pretty sure the answer is nope but does anyone know if its possible to change the label of "Customer" that shows up next to all communities usersnames in the new communities portal?

Its a troublesome word for one of my clients so they'd love to hide it or change it to something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way we ended up doing this was with some css magic in the header file

```
.chatterUserGuestBadge {
word-spacing: -999px;
letter-spacing: -999px;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

and if you want to replace it with something

```
.chatterUserGuestBadge:after {
content: "(Coach)";
visibility: visible;
word-spacing: normal;
letter-spacing: normal;
}
```

you can replace the content with any text you want

not a perfect solution but it does work

Answer (score 7):

(Customer) shows up when the CompanyName field on a Customer Community User's CompanyName field is blank. You could either populate this field with a more acceptable value across the board. Also, when creating a User from a Contact, you could populate the field with the Account's Name.

Answer (score 3):

SalesForce gave control over this in the Winter 2017 release.   See  https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_networks_profiles_custom_community_role.htm

go to Communities- All Communities- select "Workspaces" next to the relevant community - then Administration - Members - Community Role - (select custom)

Answer (score 0):

- From Setup, enter Digital Experiences in the Quick Find box, then
- select All Sites. Click Workspaces for the site you’d like to
  access.
- Under Administration, click Members. Under Site Role, select
  Custom. Enter the new name you want to use instead of the role name.
  You can replace any or all of the names. You can even remove a role
  by deleting the role name. Click Save.